# X509Certificate2 to EccKey

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt

Can anyone tell me how to get a EccKey from A X509Certificate?
I`ve tried to search on the internet, but without any luck.

My main goal si to make a request wich needs a JWT Token.
The webservice that i`m calling expects the following object :

public class Ecc256ProofKey

```
{

    [DataMember(Name = "alg", Order = 0)]
    public string Algorithm { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "kty", Order = 1)]
    public string KeyType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "use", Order = 2)]
    public string Use { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "crv", Order = 3)]
    public string CurveType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "x", Order = 4)]
    public string X { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "y", Order = 5)]
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

I`m very new to cryptography, i only have the certificate and i need to make this request.

Thanks in advance, any kind of help will be really appreciated, i`m struggling with this one for about 10 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve managed to find a way to deal with those things:) but its too large to post it here.
If anyone is interested, please PM.

Big thanks to all 9 visitors:D

Comment: Hey Florin, would love to know more about your solution. There is no PM in stackoverflow, what's best way to contact? Thank you!

Comment: hello, just send me an email: florin_vlasceanu@outlook.com